# Listen to changes from nested model attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a model attribute which is an object:

```
name : "testing",
orderCondition: {
  minOrderAmount: 20, 
  deliveryCostRequire: "MIN_ORDER_AMOUNT", 
  deliveryCostAmount: 5.55
}
```

When I use `listenTo` like this, the `render` function is not called

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "change:orderCondition", this.render); // NO FIRING
```

But when I use `listenTo` on other attributes, it works.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "change:name", this.render); // FIRING
```

Why `listenTo` doesn't see changes in nested objects but see  them in simple attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to make the nested object attribute trigger a `change` event is to replace the whole object with the new one. The most straightforward way with a simple `set`:

```
model.set('orderCondition', _.extend({}, model.get('orderCondition'), {
    deliveryCostRequire: "TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT"
}));
```

Making a function to set nested attributes on the model is a good way to encapsulate that complexity.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

    setDeliveryCostRequire: function(value, options) {
        // build a new object for 'orderCondition'
        var newOrderCondition = _.extend({}, this.get('orderCondition'), {
            deliveryCostRequire: value
        });
        // replace 'orderCondition' with the new object.
        this.set({ orderCondition: newOrderCondition }, options);
        // optionally trigger a custom event for it.
        this.trigger('change:deliveryCostRequire', this, value, options);
        return this;
    },
});
```

This is the basic concept.

[Backbone.epoxy](http://epoxyjs.org/) is a two-way binding library which also offers computed fields for models which achieves the same as above, but with the additional benefit of being completely transparent from outside the model.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    computeds: {
        deliveryCostRequire: {
            deps: ['orderCondition'],
            get: function(orderCondition) {
                return orderCondition && orderCondition.deliveryCostRequire;
            },
            set: function(value) {
                return {
                    orderCondition: _.extend({}, this.get('orderCondition'), {
                        deliveryCostRequire: value
                    })
                };
            },
        },
        deliveryCostAmount: { /* ...other computed... */ },
    }
});
```

With this model, you could do the following:

```
model.set('deliveryCostRequire', 'TOTAL_ORDER_AMOUNT');
model.get('deliveryCostRequire');
this.listenTo(model, 'change:deliveryCostRequire', this.render);
```

I also made [a simple way to bubble up events of nested models and collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40532592/1218980).

Answer (score 0):

Simply because Backbone doesn't work with nested objects. For example you can not `set` an attribute of an object property via `model.set()`.

Your `this.listenTo` is only listening to the change of entire object, not it's properties.

You can try using libraries like [backbone-deep-model](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model) for nested object support.

Comment: I can set attribute using model.get like this     `this.model.get("orderCondition").minOrderAmount = Some value;`

Comment: @ThePrzemyslaw94 `.` is not backbone setter. Backbone only lets you access direct attribute of properties, here `this.model.get("orderCondition")` events and anything else doesn't work below that level by default.