# Backbone model.set on a nested object in the response

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I have an API response that has a nested object like below -

```
{
    name: '',
    age: '',
    departments: {
        size: '',
        head: ''
    }

}
```

How do I set the head attribute of the `departments` object?

I tried doing the below

```
model.get('departments').set({
    head: 'abc'
})
```

this throws an error model.get(...).set is not a function.

**EDIT:**

tried doing -

```
 model.set('departments', {'head': 'abc'});
```

This will set the head attribute in the `departments` object. However, it rips off the size attribute from the `departments` object in the response.

Is there a better way to do this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this using the clone function from underscore. Below is the solution -

```
  var departmentObj = _.clone(model.get('departments'));
      departmentObj.head = 'abc';
      model.set({
        'departments': departmentObj
      });
```

This should do the job.

Comment: You don't need to clone the object. `set` isn't working on the nested `department` object because it's not a Backbone model. You could have just done `model.get('departments').head = 'abc';` but no events would be fired.

Comment: I need the proper events to be fired. So doing what you told wont work for me.

Comment: That's what I explain in details in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41701463/1218980).

Comment: Ah, now i see the answer !. Thank you @EmileBergeron