# Backbone model fetch() not calling parse

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two functions that call fetch on a Backbone model.  The first one creates a new instance of a model using an id and calls fetch(), the second one retrieves an existing model instance from a collection using id and calls fetch().  In the first one, the model's parse function is triggered, but not on the second one...and I don't know why.

First one (triggers parse)

```
App.fetchItemById = function (id) {
    App.myItem = new App.Item({id: id});
    App.myItem.fetch({
        traditional: true,
        data: {
            elements: 'all',
            format:'json',
        },
        success: function(){
            App.myItemView = new App.ItemView({
                el: $('#active-item'),
                model: App.myItem,
            });
            App.myItemView.render();
        }
    });
};
```

Second one (doesn't trigger parse)

```
App.fetchItemFromCollectionById = function (id) {
    App.myItem = App.myItemCollection.get(id);
    App.myItem.fetch({
        traditional: true,
        data: {
            elements: 'all',
            format:'json',
        },
        success: function(){
            App.myItemView = new App.ItemView({
                el: $('#active-item'),
                model: App.myItem,
            });
            App.myItemView.render();
        }
    });
};
```

All of the documentation I've read says that the model's parse function is ALWAYS called on fetch.

Anyone know why parse isn't triggered on the second one?

Here's the model definition:

```
App.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/v1/item/',
    defaults: {

    },
    initialize: function(){

    },
    parse : function(response){
        console.log('parsing');
        if (response.stat) {
            if (response.content.subitems) {
                this.set(‘subitems’, new App.SubitemList(response.content.subitems, {parse:true}));
                delete response.content.subitems;
                this
            }

            return response.content;
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    },
});
```

**FIXED, THANKS TO EMILE & COREY - SOLUTION BELOW**

Turns out, when I first load the App.MyItemCollection, the models in the collection were just generic models, not correctly cast as instances of App.Item.  Adding "model: App.Item" to the collection definition solved the problem.  See below:

ORIGINAL

```
App.ItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/v1/item/',
    parse : function(response){
        if (response.stat) {
            return _.map(response.content, function(model, id) {
                model.id = id;
                return model;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

UPDATED, SOLVED PROBLEM

```
App.ItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/v1/item/',
    model: App.Item,
    parse : function(response){
        if (response.stat) {
            return _.map(response.content, function(model, id) {
                model.id = id;
                return model;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that `app.myItemCollection.get(cid)` returns a valid model with an `id` attribute? Are you sure that the second `fetch` succeed?

Comment: Yes and yes.  The model with the correct id is passed to the fetch:success function.

Comment: Perhaps I spoke too soon.  Standby.

Comment: Confirmed.  The model has an id attribute both pre and post fetch, and the fetch:success callback is triggered.

Comment: Then, which version are you using?

Comment: Which version of Backbone?  1.2.0

Comment: I'm on my phone right now but you should check the documentation and the source for that specific version. Or update to the latest version if possible. I'll definitely update my answer with 1.2 in mind when I get back to my computer.

Comment: I updated to 1.3.3 and have the same issue.

Comment: Next step, we would need to see the `App.Item`, and which version of underscore?

Comment: I added the model definition to the main post.

Comment: Underscore is 1.8.3

Comment: What does the `myItemCollection` look like? Is the `model` property set to use `App.Item` as it's model?

Comment: I updated my answer with a lot of information that might help. But Cory is right, there's no problem in the code shown as of now. Now, we would need to see your collection.

Comment: @CoryDanielson, that was it!  When I first load the collection, I wasn't correctly casting the models as instances of App.Item.  When I added that, it worked.  Thank you.  I'll update my question with working code.

Comment: You're not really applying correctly what Cory and I are saying, and I updated my answer with an example using your code.

Comment: :)  Fixed.  Added model:App.Item to the collection definition and made sure parse always returns something.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `parse` is only called on successful `fetch`

In the [Backbone source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/678aeee94d7802967b52ed8a9177620659b825ee/backbone.js#L599-611), we can see that the `parse` function is only called when the `fetch` async request succeeds.

```
fetch: function(options) {
  options = _.extend({parse: true}, options);
  var model = this;
  var success = options.success;

  // The success callback is replaced with this one.
  options.success = function(resp) {
    // parse is called only if the fetch succeeded
    var serverAttrs = options.parse ? model.parse(resp, options) : resp;
    // ...snip...
    // then the provided callback, if any, is called
    if (success) success.call(options.context, model, resp, options);

  };
  wrapError(this, options);
  return this.sync('read', this, options);
},
```

The [documentation on `parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) says:

> **parse** is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in
>   `fetch`, and `save`.

Supposing that `fetch` fails, no model data is returned by the server, so parse won't be called.

For `fetch` to succeed with an existing model, the default behavior requires that the model has an `id` in its `attributes` hash.

The [`cid`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid) is only used to distinguish models locally and won't work on its own for a fetch.

> A special property of models, the **cid** or **client id** is a unique
>   identifier automatically assigned to all models when they're first
>   created. Client ids are handy when the model has not yet been saved to
>   the server, and does not yet have its eventual true id, but already
>   needs to be visible in the UI.

---

## Make sure a collection uses our own model

As [mentioned by Cory Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212079/backbone-model-fetch-not-calling-parse?noredirect=1#comment81411237_47212079), if the [`model` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) is not set on the `myItemCollection` collection, the default model `parse` will be called, not your `App.Item` model's `parse`.

Models shouldn't be instantiated in the `parse` function as it's a responsibility of the collection.

```
App.ItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Item, // make sure to set this property
    url: '/api/v1/item/',
    parse : function(response){
        if (response.stat) {
            return _.map(response.content, function(model, id) {
                model.id = id;
                return model;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

If we don't set the [`model` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) on the collection, anytime we'll use `add` or `set` on the collection, we'll be facing the same problem where our new models will be `Backbone.Model` instances instead of `App.Item` instances.

---

## Avoid side-effects in `parse`

Your `parse` function has some code smell you should know about:

- **`parse` shouldn't have any side-effects** on the model. It should receive data and return transformed data, that's it.
- It should **always return data**. In your case, it only returns data under a condition, and returns `undefined` otherwise.
- Using **`delete` is inefficient** and it's better to just return a new object. Anyway, that's another side-effect that you should avoid.

## Be careful with nested models and collections

That being said, I see that you're nesting a collection within the `attributes` hash of your model, within the parsing. I would advise against that pattern for a couple reasons:

- **The model becomes really fragile**, where you need to be really careful to always call `parse: true`, and never set `subitems` outside the model.
- It creates all the models for the subitems as soon as a model is created, which is inefficient with a lot of models. **Lazy initializing** the sub-items would help.
- Using the **`default` is now more complex** since you have to keep in mind that there's a collection within the attributes.
- **Saving the model is more complex** for the same reason.
- Changes within the **subitems won't trigger events** in the parent model.

There are multiple solutions to these which I already answered here:

- [How to use a collection within a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40823148/1218980)
- [Listen to changes from nested model attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41701463/1218980)
- [Bubble events of nested models and collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40532592/1218980)

Comment: The model has an id attribute both pre and post fetch, and the fetch:success callback is triggered.  I'm only using cid to get the object from the collection.

Comment: Changed from using cid to id, same result.

Comment: Thanks Emile, great info.  The problem was that I wasn't casting the models as instances of App.Item when loading my collection.  I'll post the working solution in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your collection isn't using the same model class for it's model property. That's why parse on that particular model would not be called.

If the `model` property isn't set to the model that you expect, it's not going to call parse on that model. By default the collection will use a Backbone.Model.

```
MyItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Item
});
```

What you might have is something like this

```
MyItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/api/v1/item/'
    })
});
```